# Problems with converting text to date (YYYY-MM-DD) in Excel (Mac)

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2011

I have been able to convert this date to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm but not anymore. What can I do to convert this date.

Sep 15, 2014 9:30:32 AM

You need to know that I'm using Swedish keyboard, date and region.

Example:

`Order #   Purchased On
100026881   Sep 15, 2014 9:30:32 AM
100026880   Sep 15, 2014 9:10:56 AM
100026879   Sep 15, 2014 9:09:10 AM
100026878   Sep 15, 2014 9:03:27 AM
100026877   Sep 15, 2014 8:57:02 AM
100026876   Sep 15, 2014 8:38:37 AM
100026875   Sep 15, 2014 6:54:29 AM
100026874   Sep 15, 2014 5:03:23 AM
100026873   Sep 15, 2014 2:45:50 AM
100026872   Sep 15, 2014 1:42:26 AM
100026871   Sep 14, 2014 11:20:31 PM
100026870   Sep 14, 2014 11:16:29 PM
100026869   Sep 14, 2014 11:11:15 PM
100026868   Sep 14, 2014 11:10:06 PM
100026867   Sep 14, 2014 10:42:56 PM
100026866   Sep 14, 2014 10:41:22 PM
100026865   Sep 14, 2014 10:36:43 PM
100026863   Sep 14, 2014 10:26:13 PM`

Comment: Please provide some details of how you have attempted to convert that is not working.

Comment: Which Office version You are using? Office 2011?

Comment: Office 2011 for Mac, I'm trying to use format cells and date, but no luck.

Comment: Was it copied from a website? Perhaps one or more of those spaces is actually a non-breaking space (e.g. CHAR(160) vs CHAR(32))

Comment: The date is from a magento database (a csv-file from the beginning, converted with text to data), I cant change the output standard for the date.

Comment: WHy can't you? Does it throw an error or give the wrong result?

Comment: When I paste those dates into Excel it recognizes them with no special formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment since I have neither Swedish settings not a Mac but I am suggesting a lookup table:

```
+-----+----+
| Jan |  1 |
| Feb |  2 |
| Mar |  3 |
| Apr |  4 |
| May |  5 |
| Jun |  6 |
| Jul |  7 |
| Aug |  8 |
| Sep |  9 |
| Oct | 10 |
| Nov | 11 |
| Dec | 12 |
+-----+----+
```

say named Marray, along with:

```
 =TEXT(DATE(MID(B2,9,4),VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2,3),Marray,2,0),MID(B2,5,2))+VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(B2,11))),"[$-41D]mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

in C2 and copied down to suit (assuming `Sep 15, 2014 9:30:32 AM` is in B2).

For single digit dates, perhaps:

`=TEXT(DATE(TRIM(MID(B2,8,5)),VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2,3),Marray,2,0),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(B2,4,3)),",",""))+VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(B2,11))),"[$-41D]mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM")`

For me (Windows, Excel 2013, English!) this returns:

[image: SO25849520 example]

It may be necessary to replace all `,`s with `;`, except one inside SUBSTITUTE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pnuts but what does "$-41D" do?

Comment: And I have a  problem when this code when the date changes the number of characters ex.  `100026642 Sep 9, 2014 11:54:55 PM`

Comment: It is very confusing this because my colleague could get this sorted on date before OSX update... @pnuts

Answer (score 1):

### Formatting a date in Excel 2011 for Mac

You have at least three different ways to apply a date format. Perhaps the fastest is to select a cell or cell range, and then click the `Home tab` of the Ribbon. In the `Number` group, click the `pop-up button` under the `Number group title` and choose `Date` to display the date as `m/d/yy`, where **m** represents the `month`'s number, **d** represents the `day` number, and **yy** represents a two-digit `year`.

Excel has many more built-in date formats, which you can apply by displaying the Format Cells dialog by pressing Command-1 and then clicking the Number tab. You can also display the Number tab of the Format Cells dialog by clicking the Home tab on the Ribbon. Then click the pop-up button under the Number group title and choose Custom from the pop-up menu.

When the Format Cells dialog displays, select the Date category. Choose a Type from the list. Choosing a different Location (language) or Calendar type changes the date types offered.
[image]

I hope this may helps..

Comment: Thats the problem it do not work with select cell and format cell to date. I dont know why. @Gagan

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Jeeped` might be close to the problem.

My guess is that now the data may have been pasted as text, instead of recognizing the date. (`pnuts` had an answer but it's a lot more work than using the builtin Excel functions.)

If the dates are in their own column, like:

```
     Sep 15, 2014 9:30:32 AM
     Sep 15, 2014 9:10:56 AM
     Sep 15, 2014 9:09:10 AM
     etc
```

Then you might have to get Excel to parse the text dates.

If the date text is in `B2`, put this formula in another cell (say `B3`):

```
     =DATEVALUE(B2) + TIMEVALUE(B2)
```

Then you can format with this custom formatting string: `yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss AM/PM`

Which will give you:

```
      2014-09-15 9:30:32 AM
      2014-09-15 9:10:56 AM
      2014-09-15 9:09:10 AM
      etc.
```

Hope this helps.